# How to use Bootstrap 4 with ReactJS + Webpack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm building my first ReactJS/Relay project with Bootstrap 4 and webpack.

It seens there are 2 ways to go using Bootstrap 4:

[react-bootstrap4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-4): As far as I understood you can get react components directly as ReactJS components (easy to use on JSX).

[bootstrap-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader): The loader for Webpack.

I could not understand if I need to use one of them, both and the differences.

What is the way to go to use Boostrap 4 with ReactJS ?

Comment: your best choice would be the react-bootstrap4. using bootstrap loader is not ideal as it injects the javascript just like how you would integrate jquery into react.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/), follow the documentation on the homepage it should be enough. Simply you create a react-app using the popularly used `create-react-app` which include webpack.
For list of components check this [Components page](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/alerts/).